# Which gods do Vaishnavites believe are only positions attained by Jivas due to Karmaphala?

Tags: vaishnavism

Indra drank Amrita and so he cannot die. How can this be reconciled with "Indra" just being a position? If an Indra or a Brahma dies, would another jiva immediately take that palce?  What stops two Jivas attaining one of these positions at the same time?

Comment: Drinking Amrita doesn't actually make you live forever, it just gives you a long life.  The position of Indra lasts for one Manvantara, and this is a universal belief of Hindus in general, not just Vaishnavas.  In any case, Sri Vaishnavas believe that everyone other than Vishnu in his various forms - Para, Vyuha, Vibhava, Antaryami, and Archa - is a Jiva, whether they're a Baddha Jiva, a Nitya Suri, or a Mukta.

Comment: "What about Lakshmi?" That's an area where Thenkalais and Vadakalais disagree.  Thenkalais consider Lakshmi a Nitya Suri, whereas Vadakalais consider her to be Paramatma.

Comment: "What stops two Jivas attaining one of these positions at the same time?" - brahman

Comment: also, there are multiple anda-katahas, each with its own brahma,rudra,indras. so multiple jivas do get the same position, but in different cosmoses.